# Ternary Operator issue

Tags: php

I was expecting the output would be:

> http://domain.dev/category/123

But the actual output is: `""`

```
$condition = true;
$categoryId = 123;
$result = 'http://domain.dev/category' . empty($condition) ? '' : '/' . $categoryId;

var_dump($result);
```

From what I understand - it check if `empty($condition)` is empty - if true then append `http://domain.dev/category` with `''` OR else `/$categoryId`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What you're actually checking there is whether `'http://domain.dev/category . empty($condition)` is "truthy" - which it always is - so the empty string is returned.

Comment: @CD001 Ahhh now I get it :) missed the first part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just put `()` around statement:

```
$result = 'http://domain.dev/category' . (empty($condition) ? '' : '/' . $categoryId);
```

so it's treated as operator